# IGenerator not called at all

Tags: dsl, xtext

I have a really strange problem. I'm trying to implement a code generator from my dsl, but the  Generator class doesn't get called at all.

The compiler in the runtime instance in the preference page is activated,also build automatically. I tried also to clean the runtime workspace and to create new projects, but without success. In debug mode the method doesn't get called at all.

The binding in the code is done by the generated `Abstract*RuntimeModule`. Any idea what's the problem? I use Xtext 2.7.2

Answer (score 2):

the project needs
`org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared.xtextNature` and `org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared.xtextBuilder`. (Have a look at Right-Click Configure menu on the project) You have to Enable Build automatically and the model files should be error free.

Try the following steps

- create a new Xtext Project with the Wizard
- Generate the Hello World Language
- Enable the Code in the Pre-Generated MyDslGenerator.xtend
- Start a Runtime Eclipse App
- Create a new General -> Project
- Create a new File "test.mydsl" in that project (ask yes if asked for nature)
- Fill it with some contents and save it

You can try to debug in `org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.handleChangedContents(Delta, IBuildContext, EclipseResourceFileSystemAccess2)` and in `org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.doBuild(ToBeBuilt, IProgressMonitor, BuildType)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I created the Hello World Project. There was no IGenerator, but I created one and binded it to the Module.  For the example project it works!

Now for my project: new BuildData(getProject().getName(), null, toBeBuilt, queuedBuildData, indexingOnly).isEmpty() returns true and cancels the job. I'm not sure why.

The project contain the nature and the xtextBuilder.

Comment: there is no `/org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/generator/MyDslGenerator.xtend` in your project? are your sure your installation is ok? that file should have been generated by the `fragment = generator.GeneratorFragment auto-inject {}`in the workflow. but if there is nothing to be built at all: are you sure the file extension is correct? maybe it has extra spaces in some configs (check plugin.xml, the workflow and the generated Abstract module)

Comment: I used the "org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel" I think that's the same. DomainmodelLanguage.mwe2 has "fragment = generator.GeneratorFragment {}" without auto-inject.

Comment: Hi,if you use Xbase it is a completely different topic. Xbase already binds `JvmModelGenerator`as IGenerator for you. so you should subclass that class and override `org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.AbstractDomainmodelRuntimeModule.bindIGenerator()` - what is the reason you are not fine with the default jvmmodelinferrer? - and in that case the project should be a java project and the model file in a source folder

Comment: and you should add a dependency to xbase/xtend lib to that project

Comment: No, I don't use JvmModelGenerator. I Want to generate a non java files  and I don't use Xbase. Not sure if that's relevant, but I have two dsl's. The second one extends the first one and the second one must generate artifact files, for which i want to create generators.

Comment: in doBuild has no deltas.. Maybe that's the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: can you share your dsl projects and your example model project

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot isolate the grammar. When I copy the grammar to a new created project it works. I decided to start from a new project and add all changes again. I will let you know if i find the cause.

Comment: I think(not 100% sure) the problem was the file extension. I have changed the file extension from ".bla" to ".BLA". The highlighting hat worked, but the generator not. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

For Googlers, this is the simple solution to the OP's problem:

As the OP mentioned in their final comment to Christian Dietrich's answer, it appears that the file extension **is** case sensitive when it comes to generating code.

I find this confusing, because it **is not** case sensitive when creating a file that recognizes the grammar of a DSL.

I'm using XText 2.10.0